# Java: How do I pipe InputStream to standard out?

Tags: java, io

Is there an easy (therefore quick) way to accomplish this? Basically just take some input stream, could be something like a socket.getInputStream(), and have the stream's buffer autmoatically redirect to standard out?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

There are no easy ways to do it, because `InputStream` has a pull-style interface, when `OutputStream` has a push-style one. You need some kind of pumping loop to pull data from `InputStream` and push them into `OutputStream`. Something like this (run it in a separate thread if necessary):

```
int size = 0;
byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
while ((size = in.read(buffer)) != -1) out.write(buffer, 0, size);
```

It's already implemented in Apache Commons IO as `IOUtils.copy()`

Comment: Would Apache Common's IO tools help?

Comment: @Zombies: Yes, you can use `IOUtils.copy()`

Comment: @axtavt - As a general rule it is a bad idea to do byte-wise operations on an unbuffered stream.  You may end up doing a system call for each call to `read(byte)` and `write(byte)`, and that is very expensive.

Comment: copy(inputStream, System.out) ?

Comment: @Zombies: Yes. And you should run it in a separate thread in you don't want to block your current thread

Answer (score 4):

Since Java 9, you can use `InputStream.transferTo`

Example

```
try (InputStream stream = Application.class.getResourceAsStream("/test.txt")) {
    stream.transferTo(System.out);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You need a simple thread which reads from the input stream and writes to standard output. Make sure it yields to other threads.